# Getting/Setting Values Within SuiteScript 2.0 Custom Module

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm running into an issue with reading values from a custom module that are set by running a trigger function in the module to populate the values. For example, something like the following within the "define":

```
var _settings = {
        a : "a"
    ,   b : "b"
};

function buildSettings() {
    // run scripting to add values to _settings
    _settings.c = "c";
    _settings.d = "d";
}

return {
        SETTINGS : _settings
    ,   build : buildSettings
}
```

I've had situations in a development account where this has worked just fine. However, I've been running into issues where the values created by "buildSettings" are not available when trying to reference the data from outside of the custom module except for "a" and "b". If "buildSettings" was adding say "c" and "d", "c" and "d" can be read from within the module but not from the script to which the module has been attached. So, take the following:

```
define(['./custom-module'], function(custMod) {

    function logValues() {
        custMod.build();
        
        console.log(custMod.SETTINGS.a);
        console.log(custMod.SETTINGS.b);
        console.log(custMod.SETTINGS.c);
        console.log(custMod.SETTINGS.d);
    }
    
    return {
        logValues : logValues
    };
    
});
```

If you call "logValues()", what you'll see in the console would be something like the following:

```
// undesired results
"a"
"b"
null
null
```

I can't understand, though, why in some systems this would work correctly and you'd get the following instead:

```
// desired results
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
```

Is there something I'm not seeing that would allow this to get the expected results instead of getting empty values? Because I've had this problem when building in a dev account, no problem when building in a different dev account, and re-encountered the problem when copying from the second dev account to another account.